# Junit Mocking throwing Null pointer

Tags: junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock the below service class.

I have created a separate Config bean which I'm calling as you can see below in the code:-

```
@Component
public class CrawlerService implements CrawlerServiceInterface {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrawlerService.class);

    private final CrawlConfig config;

    @Autowired
    CrawlerFactory crawlerFactory;

    @Autowired
    public CrawlerService(@Qualifier(value = "CrawlerConfig") CrawlConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Value("${com.prudential.noOfCrawlers}")
    private int numberOfCrawlers;

    @Override
    public Object crawlService(String URL, int max) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info("In Service Class");

        this.config.setMaxPagesToFetch(max);

        PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
        RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
        RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
        CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);

        controller.addSeed(URL);
        controller.start(crawlerFactory, numberOfCrawlers);

        List<Object> crawlersLocalData = controller.getCrawlersLocalData();

        LOGGER.info("End of Service Class");
        return crawlersLocalData;

    }

}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a null pointer exception in `this.config.setMaxPagesToFetch`.

What am I doing wrong?

If I mocked some dependent object with `@Mock` annotation, does it mean it won't allow the value to be changed?

Here is the test class:-

```
List<Object> obj=new ArrayList<Object>();

@Mock
private CrawlConfig config;

@Mock
CrawlerFactory crawlerFactory;

@Mock
CrawlController controller;

@InjectMocks
CrawlerService crawlerService = new CrawlerService(config);

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testService() throws Exception {
    when(controller.getCrawlersLocalData()).thenReturn(obj);

    assertEquals(crawlerService.crawlService("https://vogella.com", 10), obj);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the problem with mock creating order. First of all, let's see what is happening here:

- First, you are declaring some fields. In this case, you are declaring `private CrawlConfig config` and `CrawlerService crawlerService`. But `crawlerService` you don't just declare but initialize as well.
- When you initialize it, you are passing as a dependency to it `CrawlConfig config` which is `null`.
- Then `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` start doing it's magic. What does it do? It initializes all the fields annotated with `@Mock`, then it tries to initialize the `@InjectMocks` if it's not already initialized. In your case it is already initialized, so mockito won't initialize it and will use the instance which you created.
- After that the mock injection takes part. Mockito will try to use any of it's strategy to inject mocks. You can read more about it in [@InjectMocks javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html). So in your case, `mockito` will try to use property setter or field injection. However, the `CrawlConfig config` in your `CrawlerService` is declared `final`, and `mockito` will ignore this field, as for this type of injection `mockito` ignores `final` or `static` fields.

So here you have created an instance of `CrawlerService` with dependency `CrawlConfig config` which is `null` and `mockito` won't do anything about it.

1) You can mock the `CrawlConfig config` by yourself before `mockito` is going to:

```
private CrawlConfig config = Mockito.mock(CrawlConfig.class);

@InjectMocks
CrawlerService crawlerService = new CrawlerService(config);
```

2) You can omit the initialization of the `CrawlerService` and rely on `mockito`:

```
@Mock
private CrawlConfig config = Mockito.mock(CrawlConfig.class);

@InjectMocks
CrawlerService crawlerService;
```

Each of these methods should work.

You can as well remove the `final` declaration from your `CrawlerService` and it will also work. But as for me, the two methods above are better options.